# PHPUnit: How can I mock this file creation?

Tags: php, symfony, unit-testing, phpunit, vfs-stream

I want to mock the creation of a file using the `vfsstream`

```
class MyClass{

  public function createFile($dirPath)
  {
    $name = time() . "-RT";
    $file = $dirPath . '/' . $name . '.tmp';

    fopen($file, "w+");
    if (file_exists($file)) {
        return $name . '.tmp';
    } else {
        return '';
    }
  }
}
```

but when I try to test the file creation :

```
$filename = $myClass->createFile(vfsStream::url('/var/www/app/web/exported/folder'));
```

I get an error :

> failed to open stream: "org\bovigo\vfs\vfsStreamWrapper::stream_open"
>   call failed fopen(vfs://var/www/app/web/exported/folder)

I have see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12083134/phpunit-how-do-i-mock-this-file-system) talking about mocking the fileSystem but it has no information about the file creation.
Does the vfsstream support the file creation with the fopen function?
How can I test the file creation?

Comment: Last time I looked, this is explained in [the documentation of vfs-stream](https://github.com/mikey179/vfsStream/wiki). You need to init it first and then relate to the root, see the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/44776218/367456 below.

Answer (score 3):

try creating with a setup the vsf stream, as example:

```
$root = vfsStream::setup('root');
$filename = $myClass->createFile($root->url());
```

hope this help

As working example:

```
/**
 * @test
 * @group unit
 */
public function itShouldBeTested()
{
    $myClass = new MyClass();

    $root = vfsStream::setup('root');
    $filename = $myClass->createFile($root->url());
    $this->assertNotNull($filename);
    var_dump($filename);
}
```

this will produce

> (dev) bash-4.4$ phpunit -c app --filter=itShouldBeTested PHPUnit
>   4.8.26 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
>
> .string(17) "1498555092-RT.tmp"
>
> Time: 13.11 seconds, Memory: 200.00MB
>
> OK (1 test, 1 assertion)

Answer (score 0):

The OOP way would be like this:

```
interface FileClientInterface {
    function open($path);
    function exist($path);
}

class FileClient implements FileClientInterface {
    function open($path)
    {
        fopen($path, "w+");
    }

    function exist($path)
    {
        return file_exists($path);
    }
}

class MyClass
{
    private $fileClient;

    /**
     * MyClass constructor.
     * @param $fileClient
     */
    public function __construct(FileClientInterface $fileClient)
    {
        $this->fileClient = $fileClient;
    }

    public function createFile($dirPath)
    {
        $name = time() . "-RT";
        $file = $dirPath . '/' . $name . '.tmp';

        $this->fileClient->open($file);
        fopen($file, "w+");
        if ($this->fileClient->exist($file)) {
            return $name . '.tmp';
        } else {
            return '';
        }

    }
}

class MockFileClient implements FileClientInterface {
    public $calledOpen = 0;
    public $calledExists = 0;

    public function open($path)
    {
        $this->calledOpen ++;
    }

    public function exist($path)
    {
        $this->calledExists++;
    }

}


//not the test
$mockFileClient = new MockFileClient();
$myClass = new MyClass($mockFileClient);
$myClass->createFile('/test/path');

print_r($mockFileClient->calledOpen . PHP_EOL);
print_r($mockFileClient->calledExists . PHP_EOL);
```

So we are creating an interface (FileClientInterface) and two implementing classes, one for production one for tests (the one with mock). The testing implementation just increments a counter when it's method are called. This way we decouple the actual I/O methods in the test.