# Mocked protected method not returning value set in mock

Tags: php, phpunit, mockery, laravel-10

I have a class called `ModuleManifest` with this constructor:

```php
/**
 * Create a new instance of the ModuleManifest class.
 *
 * @param string $vendor The vendor of the module.
 * @param string $package The name of the package.
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct(string $vendor, string $package)
{
    $manifest = $this->manifestPath($vendor, $package);

    if (!File::exists($manifest))
    {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf(
            'Package %s from vendor %s does not contain a manifest',
            $package, $vendor
        ));
    }

    $this->manifest = $this->load($manifest);
}
```

This constructor loads a json file with the `load` method.

```php
/**
 * Load a module manifest into an object.
 *
 * @param string $path The path to the module.
 * @return object
 */
protected function load(string $path) : object
{
    return json_decode(file_get_contents($path));
}

/**
 * Determine the path to the module manifest.
 *
 * @param string $vendor The vendor of the module.
 * @param string $package The name of the package.
 * @return string
 */
protected function manifestPath(string $vendor, string $package) : string
{
    return implode('/', [base_path('vendor'), $vendor, $package, 'resources/manifest.json']);
}
```

I want determine whether the method is returning an object:

```php
/** @testdox Returns an object when the path exists */
public function test_manifest_returns_object() : void
{
    File::shouldReceive('exists')->once()->andReturnTrue();

    $this->mock(ModuleManifest::class, function (MockInterface $mock) {
        $mock->shouldAllowMockingProtectedMethods();
        $mock->shouldReceive('load')->once()->andReturn(
            json_decode('{"name": "testModule"}')
        );
    });

    $manifest = new ModuleManifest('vendor', 'package');

    $this->assertTrue($manifest->has('name'));
}
```

I get the error:

> ErrorException: file_get_contents(...): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory

I would expect it to return the result of `json_decode('{"name": "testModule"}')`, but it tries to call the function normally. How to resolve this? I have tried to create a partial mock, but the issue remains.

Comment: I don't fully understand why your original method is called, but I can tell you that the testing approach is not sound. You are modifying the SUT (already a smell) and then asserting against something that is basically a fake (the `load` method is not the real one). Even if it worked, you'd be verifying your mock instead of the SUT. The design isn't testable. I suggest you avoid IO in the constructor, it should not "do" things. If you are writing unit tests, mock an (injected) IO collaborator. If it's an integration test, do not use mocks, create a real json file fixture and verify this works.

Comment: @istepaniuk This makes sense, what changes would you propose to make this code more testable?

Comment: Can you show the `manifestPath()` method?

Comment: @Olivier I added it to the post.

Comment: I think you need to type-cast the return value of `json_decode` to `(object)` in order to ensure that it returns an object and try it with `partialMock`, I can send you the rewritten function if you want.

Comment: You can use vfs to mock that file path as seen in this example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44774827/phpunit-how-can-i-mock-this-file-creation

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I would do it. Add an optional `$basePath` parameter to the constructor whose default
value is `base_path()`:

```
class ModuleManifest
{
    private object $manifest;

    public function __construct(string $vendor, string $package, string $basePath='')
    {
        if ($basePath=='')
            $basePath = base_path();
        $path = $this->manifestPath($vendor, $package, $basePath);

        if (!File::exists($path))
        {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf(
                'Package %s from vendor %s does not contain a manifest',
                $package, $vendor
            ));
        }

        $this->manifest = $this->load($path);
    }

    protected function manifestPath(string $vendor, string $package, string $basePath) : string
    {
        return implode('/', [$basePath, 'vendor', $vendor, $package, 'resources/manifest.json']);
    }

    protected function load(string $path) : object
    {
        return json_decode(file_get_contents($path));
    }

    public function has(string $key) : bool
    {
        return isset($this->manifest->$key);
    }
}
```

For the test, choose a test directory and create `vendor/foo/bar/resources/manifest.json` in it. Then the testing
code is simply:

```
public function test_manifest_returns_object() : void
{
    $manifest = new ModuleManifest('foo', 'bar', '/path/to/test/dir');
    $this->assertTrue($manifest->has('name'));
}
```

That's it. You don't need any mock. Also note that you should not test that `ModuleManifest` uses the `File` class because
it's just an implementation detail. It could very well do it another way (such as calling `file_exists()` directly).